# SQL Server replacing parts of a string using regex

Tags: sql-server, regex

This should be a simple one, though I didn't quite find a suitable solution.

I need to implement a (rather) simple replacement using SQL (SQL Server) as follows. Imagine you have a string that looks like:

```
'This is a simple example where aaa[0004] should become aaa[4] and b[0],c[1] should remain unchanged'
```

In other words, a pattern `[0004]` should become `[4]`.

I initially thought of making the replacing like:

```
  SET @MyString = REPLACE(@MyString,'[0','[') ;
```

but, even before testing it, I realized that it would also convert `[0]` to `[]`, which is not want I want.

I know how to do it quite simply in PL/SQL, but in SQL Server I'm having difficulties.

Comment: This is quite painful to do in SQL Server.

Comment: If you are allowed to use CLR assemblies, [SqlSharp](http://www.sqlsharp.com/features/) has implementations of RegEx along with a whole host of great CLR features.

Comment: Thank you @SqlZim, but no, I cannot use that type of things (company policy). I thought of searching for `[0`, from there `]`, and if there are digits in-between, replace the first `[0` with `[`. Then loop till no more such cases were found. That would work, but its ugliness causes me pain.

Answer (score 2):

Another option.  This will replace up to 25 occurrences of '[0' and multiple [...]'s per line.

**Example**

```
Declare @MyString varchar(max) = 'This [0] [000] is a simple example where aaa[0004] should become aaa[4] and test [0]'

Select @MyString = Replace(@MyString,MapFrom,MapTo)
  From (
        Select MapFrom='0]',MapTo='§§0]'
        Union All           
        Select Top 25 '[0','['  From master..spt_values 
        Union All
        Select '§§0]','0]'
        ) b 

Select @MyString
```

**Returns**

```
This [0] [0] is a simple example where aaa[4] should become aaa[4] and test [0]
```

**Note:** If processing a table, it will be a small matter to apply some XML

Comment: Nicely done. Note: this also works with the **updated** test string: http://rextester.com/VPYA60373  returning `This is a simple example where aaa[4] should become aaa[4] and b[0],c[1] should remain unchanged`

Comment: @SqlZim Thanks, sometimes you just need a hammer.  It's not elegant but gets the job done :)

Comment: You must have some fancy hammers!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, indeed, great solution that yields **ALMOST ALWAYS** the correct result. Why **ALMOST ALWAYS**? Try it with: `'This is a sample string with [] and aaa[0004]'`. The `[]` is replaced with `[0]` while it should remain unchanged. If you fix this, I'll certainly mark it as **THE** solution. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, I took Martin's suggestion as a seed and worked a similar one (with no limitation on the number of leading 0). Will be posting the solution I adopted later today. Thanks for the very interesting suggestion and sorry for not marking it as THE solution (though up-voted it for its originality).

Comment: @FDavidov The real idea was to introduce a a technique for global search and replace.  I use use similar approaches to with tokenized sql and web requests.   As you can see the ALMOST was a quick fix

Comment: Thank you John. I see and can think of many uses of it (even, make a generalize service function with parameters for what to replace with what while discarding things (like my `00000`'s). For my specific case, I took Martin's answer and made the code shown below (my own answer). Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The following would work for up to 15 leading zeroes if there is a character (`~` below) that you can be reasonably confident will never appear in the data.

```
SELECT 
 REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
     REPLACE(
       REPLACE(X,'0]', '~'), 
     '[00000000','['),
    '[0000','['),
   '[00','['),
  '[0','['),
 '~','0]')
FROM YourTable
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DMU30877)

Comment: Thank you Martin for your suggestion. I took it as a seed and worked out another solution with no limitation on the number of 0's. Will post it later today in case you are interested. Cheers!

Comment: @FDavidov - Is there in practice no limitation on the number of 0s? What kind of number is this? 15 is more than enough for a 32 bit int and you can increase the number of leading zerroes supported to 31 by adding another `REPLACE` with 16 zeroes. Procedural looping should generally be avoided in SQL Server.

Comment: Martin, I fully agree with you regarding the actual need for anything beyond 15 zeros. In practice, I don't expect more than 1-2 leading zeros. My approach (in general) is to device mechanisms that don't have a limitation at all (even when in practice a limitless condition would never happen) if the solution is not **costly**. I do not agree with you regarding your suggestion of avoiding loops within SQL. They should be used when it is **correct** to use them, and avoid them when it is not. SQL is a programming language like any other, and should be used smartly, like any other.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin's suggestion, I worked the following solution:

```
    Declare @MyString   varchar(max) ;
    Declare @MyString_T varchar(max) ;

    SET @MyString = 'This is a simple example where aaa[00000000000000000000000000004] should become aaa[40] and test [000] and ccc[]' ;

    WHILE (1=1)
        BEGIN
            SET @MyString_T = REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                  REPLACE(@MyString,'0]', '~'), 
                                '[0','['),
                              '~','0]') ;

            IF @MyString_T = @MyString
                BREAK ;
            ELSE
               SET @MyString = @MyString_T ;
        END ;

    Print(@MyString) ;
```

and the result is:

```
This is a simple example where aaa[4] should become aaa[40] and test [0] and ccc[]
```

Thanks again to Martin!!!